# Setting Django RadioSelect id

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views

I am trying to set keys as the id for the radio button options. One with `M` and one with `F`. How to do that? What is the right way to do it?

```
genders = {
    "M":"Male",
    "F":"Female"
}


Gender = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={"label":"Gender", "id":genders.fromkeys}), choices=genders.items)
#Expecting one "id"="M" and one with "id"="F"
```

Comment: inside template you could use `<label for="{{ form.gender.id_for_label }}"...`, it's not the answer of your question but it could help if you need to itreate over form fields

Comment: and also test `"id":self.genders.fromkeys`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the custom ID by overriding `id_for_label` method:

```
class MyRadioSelect(forms.RadioSelect):
    def id_for_label(self, id_, index='0'):
        """
        Use an incremented id for each option where the main widget
        references the zero index.
        """
        return self.choices[int(index)][0]



class MyForm(forms.Form):
    ...

    GENDERS = (
        ("M", "Male"),
        ("F", "Female")
    )
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(widget=MyRadioSelect, choices=GENDERS)
    
    ...
```

See [BoundField.id_for_label](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.BoundField.id_for_label)

Comment: It auto generates an  `idi` like this instead of M/F- `<input type="radio" name="gender1" value="M" required="" id="id_gender1_0">`

Comment: @Majoris, you can override `id_for_label` method of `forms.RadioSelect`. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Majoris, just tested on my server, works very well.

Comment: @Thanks! I will try after some time, will let you know.